# How to handle async reads in a remote desktop virtual channel addin

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I've got an RDP client addin which should push data from a named pipe to the remote side. Unfortunately the threading/async model doesn't seem to be documented in the [VirtualChannelWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cchannel/nc-cchannel-virtualchannelwrite) or related docs.

Am I missing some clear description or what's allowed in this situation? I could use a separate thread to read from the pipe synchronously and call VirtualChannelWrite. Or I could use ReadFileEx and hope that the app does alertable waits. If it's not documented, how would I know what's the right/allowed thing to do?

(Actually the overlapped version seems not possible unless I'm missing something. I'd have to wait for the `ConnectNamedPipe` event to finish/notify, but a `Wait...` call would block the RDP connection. So there's only callbacks on a threadpool left as an option, I guess?)